# CRTP and visibility of a type that is defined by the base class

Tags: c++, templates, visibility, crtp

Here a brief example of a code that works. It helps to introduce the actual question.
The specifiers for the visibility are the same used in the real code.

```
class Base {
public:
    using foo = int;
    virtual ~Base() { }

protected:
    static foo bar() noexcept {
        static foo v = 0;
        return v++;
    }
};

template<class Derived>
class Class: public Base {
    static foo get() noexcept {
        static foo v = bar();
        return v;
    }
};

int main() { }
```

It follows the previous example, even though slightly modified.
A template parameter has been added to the base class and the derived one has been updated accordingly.
This one doesn't compile.

```
template<typename T>
class Base {
public:
    using foo = int;
    virtual ~Base() { }

protected:
    static foo bar() noexcept {
        static foo v = 0;
        return v++;
    }
};

template<class Derived, typename T>
class Class: public Base<T> {
    static foo get() noexcept {
        static foo v = bar();
        return v;
    }
};

int main() { }
```

The error is quite clear indeed and the problem is not to solve it:

```
main.cpp:18:12: error: ‘foo’ does not name a type
     static foo get() noexcept {
            ^
main.cpp:18:12: note: (perhaps ‘typename BaseComponent<T>::foo’ was intended)
```

The actual question is: why `foo` is not visible without a scope specifier in the second example?
I mean, `Class` is derived from `Base<T>`, that is (at least in my mind) a fully defined type, thus `foo` should be part of the base class and thus visible to the derived one, as it happens in the first example.

It follows an example that, according to what I guess of the problem, actually compiles and should not, or at least should behave like the previous one:

```
template <typename T>
struct B {
    using foo = T;
};

struct D: public B<int> {
    static foo bar;
};

int main() {
    B<int> *b = new D;
}
```

Could it be due to the fact that the derived class is not a templated one in this case?
Honestly, it seems to me a bit strange, because the `foo` type is part of the base class that is still a templated one, so it shouldn't be much different from the previous one.

It goes without saying that I'm wrong, but I cannot figure out what's wrong in my thoughts.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because of name lookup rules. If your base class is a template, the unqualified name in base is not resolved. The reason is that later in your code you may have a template specialization of that base which doesn't define the name, or for which the name means something completely different. It's too complicated for the compiler to figure out whether you have a specialization, and if so, whether your name means the same thing in it. So it prefers to defer the name lookup. To make the compiler "believe you", then you need to either use a qualified name, or `this->name` instead (for members, not for typedefs), and the compiler will resolve the name.

Comment: Does `this->foo` make sense?? O.o
Note that `foo` is a type, not a data member.

Comment: @skypjack I made an edit. You use `this->member` for members, not for typedefs. But the reason stated in the answer stands. It's too complicated for the compiler to figure out whether you have a specialization, and if so, whether your name means the same thing in it. So it prefers to defer the name lookup.

Comment: You were to reveal me something never heard before with the `this->foo` syntax for aliases!! :-) ... I'm going to update the question with one more example that still I cannot explain this way.

Comment: In your last example Base<int> is not a dependant type anymore and the compiler can fully resolve it.

Comment: oh, you are right, it makes perfectly sense. thank you!! your response and your comment fully clarify my doubts, thank you, my fault not to have understood it by myself. I suggest to integrate the former with the latter to help future readers, if possible.

Comment: @skypjack Done. It makes as much perfect sense as name lookup rules make sense in C++ ;) BTW, I learned about these issues from the [*C++ Templates* book by Vandervoorde and Josuttis](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0201734842/?tag=stackoverfl08-20). It's an excellent book.

Comment: Good hint, thank you. Anyway, now that you gave me the two key clues, everything is clear enough. The problem was that I didn't manage today to put the pieces of the puzzle together. Thank you again, really appreciated. :-)